# How do i get selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i get a values of a selected ROW in the table ,when one or more rows are selected.
The following is how my table created :

```
var LoadLabels = function (data) {
  var CableInfos = eval(data);
  var newContent = '';
  var currentState = Hesto.Html.SaveTableState('#ScannedLabelList');

  if (CableInfos.length != 0) {
    $.each(CableInfos, function (i, item) {
      var sideFlag = item.KeepSideFlag;

      newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.Serial, null);
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input id="cbSerial" type="checkbox" value="" onclick="">', null);
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Serial, null);
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.KanbanNumber, null, null);
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CustomerNumber, null, null);
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Description, null, 'centerAlign');
      newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Quantity, null);
      // newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input id="deleteRow"     type="button"     value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">', null);
      newContent = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);
    });
```

here is my html tags:

```
    <table id="ScannedLabelTable" class="hesto">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                <th >Check/Uncheck</th>
                <th >Serial</th>
                <th >Kanban Number </th>
                <th >Customer Number </th>
                <th >Description </th>
                <th >Quantity</th>

             </tr>
         </thead>
             <tbody id="ScannedLabelList" class="selectionModeMulti">

        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
     </table
```

Comment: Please paste your html

Comment: Put it in the question not the comments, they don't format very well.

Comment: @Llyd now i've updated my post

Comment: Well did you manage it?

Comment: @Simon im sorry to not respond on your post ,i tried it but it does not seem to be working i dont know why.

Comment: Can you post generated HTML? So after you executed `LoadLabels()`

Comment: ColumnName : Check/Uncheck Serial Kanban Number Customer Number   Description    Quantity

Table Row  : Checked             1649 2KB-927006-002 52045476   HARNESS ASM-BODY FRT WRG (GAS)  25

Answer (score 0):

To get all checked input values do:

```
var selectedValues = new Array();
var $selectedRows = $('#ScannedLabelTable input').filter(':checked');

$selectedRows.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    selectedValues.push($row.val());
});
```